# Can I track a teams total deaths (rather than individual kills)?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a team deathmatch server, and I want to keep track of all Team Deaths on both red and blue separately, regardless of the cause of death. This is because a lot of kills involve killing with potion effects, which don't seem to count as direct kills.

I want to keep track of and add up the deaths of every member on a team. I know how to track individual deaths, but I don’t know how to add them up into one score that can be displayed and tested.

Comment: *[Comments Removed]* Hi all. Let's see if we can nip this in the bud please. @FabianRöling - I agreed with your initial 'Too Broad' vote, however your second comment's tone wasn't great. Even if a lot of new users don't do proper research before posting, doesn't mean that is the case for everyone; *"Can you show us what you've tried so far, what part are you stuck on?"* comes off a lot nicer than *"barely anyone does proper research...so I assume you haven't".* From the [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct): *"If you’re here to help others, be patient and welcoming."*

Comment: HighOnMinecraft - Firstly thanks for editing your post to be a lot clearer and to focus on a single issue you're having. However, rather than escalating with name calling, be open to feedback: *"Edits, comments, and suggestions are healthy parts of our community."* - [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct).  Show us what you've tried. *"I did search, but all I could find was [this link] about tracking individual kills"* or *"I've tried [these commands] but they aren't quite right."* is a lot more constructive and helpful to anyone looking to help you :-)

Answer (score 3):

Add the teams:

```
/scoreboard teams add Red
/scoreboard teams add Blue
```

And edit the color to Red and Blue:

```
/scoreboard teams option Red color red
/scoreboard teams option Blue color blue
```

Now add objectives for them:

```
/scoreboard objectives add DeathsRed deathCount
/scoreboard objectives add DeathsBlue deathCount
```

And setdisplay for them:

```
/scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar.team.blue DeathsBlue
/scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar.team.red DeathsRed
```

Now the team with the color will have the deaths shown.

---

If you want both teams to see the deaths, you can do it like this instead:

```
/scoreboard objectives add Deaths deathCount
/scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar Deaths
```

But keep the /scoreboard teams commands.

Reset deaths by doing:

```
/scoreboard players set @a Deaths 0
```

The deaths will show up after the player have died once or the command above has been executed.

Hope this helps, even though it's a bit messy.